# Put people in different classes based on age

Tags: sql

I have a table for users, and a table for classes. Every class has an age limit, and the user has an age column. Is there a way to make a constraint or something that puts people automatically in the right class based on their age.

```
create table if not EXISTS database.users {
    User_ID          int UNSIGNED auto_increment,
    Age              int(3),
    Class_ID         int(2)
 
    CONSTRAINT User_ID PRIMARY KEY (User_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Class_ID) REFERENCES classes(Class_ID)
}
```

```
create table if not EXISTS database.classes {
    Class_ID          int UNSIGNED auto_increment,
    Age_limit         int(3),
    Class_name        varchar(64),
 
    CONSTRAINT Class_ID PRIMARY KEY (Class_ID)
}
```

So that the Class_ID foreign key in the user table, is dependent on the users age.

The goal would be to be able to type:

```
insert into database.users (Age)
values (30);
```

And let the computer fill out the classID automatically

Comment: Which database is this? Please [edit] your question and add the right tag.

Comment: A student may match the age limit of multiple classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a DEFAULT clause for that. Mind you that next year, when both age and age-based decision will change, the already inserted row won't change automatically, though.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database.users (
    user_id   IDENTITY,
    age       SMALLINT,
    Class_ID  SMALLINT DEFAULT
      CASE
        WHEN age < 5 THEN NULL
        WHEN age BETWEEN  6 AND  7 THEN 1
        WHEN age BETWEEN  8 AND  9 THEN 2
        WHEN age BETWEEN 10 AND 11 THEN 3
        ELSE 4
      END,
    CONSTRAINT User_ID PRIMARY KEY (User_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Class_ID) REFERENCES classes(Class_ID)
)
```